# Google listed a blog post with https and I don't know why?

Tags: wordpress, https, seo, google-search

Two days ago we posted a new blog on a site with the aim of being picked up for the search term "live comedy in chippenham". It’s been indexed by Google and we’re now 2nd in the results for the search query. The bad news is that for some reason the post has been indexed as a https URL so all browsers give a warning when the link is clicked.

Firefox gives this error:

> The owner of www.neeld.co.uk has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

The host has confirmed that it's not a server config error and we have other posts and pages on the site that are being indexed correctly. We're using WordPress and the Yoast plugin. I can't see anywhere in Webmaster Tools that could be causing the problem.

Can anyone offer any advice please? If you search Google for "live comedy in chippenham" you'll see the issue (it's the link https://www.neeld.co.uk/live-comedy-in-chippenham/)?

Comment: Buy an ssl cert and install it. Would fix this right away - no waiting.

Answer (score 1):

It's a really strange one but something I've experienced before.

It has mostly likely been caused by an external link to the page using https protocol which Google has followed before indexing the page. Google are [very keen to index https pages at the moment](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/12/indexing-https-pages-by-default.html) so we might start seeing this kind of issue more often.

There's not a lot you can do other than wait for Google to realise their mistake and list the correct URL in the SERPS. You can help speed this along with a canonical link (which I can see is there), XML sitemap (which you've got) and a server level redirect of https to http.

**Do not** try to remove the page in Webmaster Tools as [this won't have the desired effect](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/Google_Webmaster_Help-Indexing) and will stop Google reindexing the page properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I think this makes sense. Facebook could well be the culprit in this case i think...

Comment: Ah great news! Glad to hear it's sorted :)